# Libsvm classes not in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, weka, libsvm

I am trying to use Weka libsvm implementation. I have installed weka - 3.6 version and I add in weka folder libsvm.jar file. I put the whole path of the .jar file in my CLASSPATH in environment variables. However when I tried to use libsvm function from the WEKA Api I am receiving the following message:  `libsvm classes not in CLASSPATH`. When I type in console `echo %CLASSPATH%` I am getting `C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\libsvm.jar` which is the libsvm file. Any idea what may be wrong?

The default batch script to run weka is using the following commands:

```
set _cmd=%1
set _java=javaw
if "%_cmd%"=="" set _cmd=default
if "%_cmd%"=="-h" set _java=java
%_java% -classpath . RunWeka -i .\RunWeka.ini -w .\weka.jar -c %_cmd% "%2"
```

I am also tried to run just the weka.jar file with java -jar weka.jar. I got the same message error in both cases.

Comment: What is your full command line for Weka?

Comment: What you mean command line? Do you mean what is the shortcut script?

Comment: Yes - java ... (are you using -jar or -cp flags)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you explicitly use the -classpath flag, the %CLASSPATH% variable is not used. You can either add libsvm to the -classpath (it's semicolon separated on windows) or add weka to the CLASSPATH variable.

Comment: I add C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6  to classpath with the libsvm.jar file and I received the following error: Trying to add database dirver JDBC jdbc.idbDriver not in classpath?

Comment: Try something like -classpath ".;C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\libsvm.jar"